Add Section to Shopify theme programmatically - directly into sections folder
Does anyone know how we can programmatically add a section to a Shopify theme? I'm not talking about app blocks or embedded apps—I mean adding a Liquid file directly to the Sections folder. I thought this wasn’t possible, but the "Section Store" app can do it, and I can’t find any REST API or GraphQL mutation that supports this operation.
I've tried everything but I can't find a mutation or REST api for this

Why do you need rest or graphQl api to add section to your storefront? You're really not encouraged to make any admin api calls from the liquid file. Why don't you just add it using liquid conditions?
